# How to pass values of radios through ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have this form with 3 radios:

```
<form id="sign" action="" method="POST" role="form">

        <!-- NAME   -->
        <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- GENDER -->
        <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="male" required>Male
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="female">Female
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline disabled">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="other">Other
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit_message" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>                          
    </form>
```

This is my jquery ajax to send the data to the php file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sign').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sign.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $('.result').show();    
                $('.result').html(data);

            }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Ant this is part of the php code (sign.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_message'])) {
    // name block
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {        
        $safeuserinput = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        if($safeuserinput == NULL){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please fill in your name!</div>';
            $error = true;  
        } else {
            $username = $safeuserinput;
        }
    }

    // gender block
    if (!isset($_POST['gender'])) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please fill in a gender!</div>';
        $error = true;
    }
    else {
        $safeuserinput = htmlentities($_POST['gender']);        
        $usergender = $safeuserinput;

    }


    ...
```

Even when i check a radio, it keeps hanging on the echo: `Please fill in a gender!`
I guess, the value of the checked radio is not been sent to the php file. 
How can i solve this problem?

is `data: $('form').serialize(),` not the correct way to sent the data?

Comment: What does print_r($_POST) look like?

Comment: It gives me`array()`